# How to get files using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple function in my controller to get certain files, here is my solution

Here is my folder structure.

[image]

`codetemplate` is the file I am  trying to get

my function in a controller to get a file.

```
   public function code($code_id)
     {
         $settings = Setting::find($code_id);

         $templatefile = file_get_contents("pages.settings/codetemplate.js");

        file_put_contents("pages/codes/" .$code_id .".js", $replacedfile );

         return view('pages.settings.code', compact('settings'));

     }
```

Now when I run my app I am getting the following error.

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_get_contents(pages.settings/codetemplate.js): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It's `pages/settings/codetemplate.js`, not `pages.settings/codetemplate.js`. The dot notation only works in `view()`, not in `file_put_contents` or `file_get_contents`.

Comment: hej ceejayoz still getting the error :(

Comment: Chances are you need the full path from the project's root, starting at `resources`.

Comment: no other way to get files from resources?

Comment: Also you can use resource_path helper `$templatefile = resource_path('views/pages/settings/codetemplate.js');`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes your right it works, you can put it as answer ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the file is under the `/resources` directory, you can use the [resource_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-resource-path) helper.

```
$templatefile = resource_path('views/pages/settings/codetemplate.js');
```

or seeing what you are doing in your code:

```
$templatefilecontent = file_get_contents( resource_path('views/pages/settings/codetemplate.js') );
```